# Adjusted R squared formula

Tags: regression

I am studying linear regression lately and I notice this adjusted r-squared formula in a youtube video:

$$adj. R^2 = \frac{\frac{SSE}{n-k}}{\frac{SSTO}{n-1}}$$

While the formula that I know is this:

$$adj. R^2 = \frac{\frac{SSE}{n-k-1}}{\frac{SSTO}{n-1}}$$

I was about to comment in the yt vid that something is wrong but some people agree with it.

1. How come that both formula seems to be applicable?
2. Why does the other one has a n-k degrees of freedom while the other has $n-k-1$?

I'm so confused. I don't think of a way that you can equate the other formula to another formula.